# Left Join two tables and get unmapped values as Unknown

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Table1 
IndexId IndexName
1       A
2       B
3       C

Table2
MapId MapName MapIndexId
1     M1      1
2     M2      2
```

I want to join two tables based on Table2.MapIndexId = Table1.IndexId and get result as

```
MapId MapName IndexId IndexName
1     M1      1        A
2     M2      2        B
-1    Unknown 3        C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(T2.MapId,-1) MapId,
       ISNULL(T2.MapName,'Unknown') MapName,
       T1.IndexId,
       T1.IndexName
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.IndexId = T2.MapIndexId
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b743/1)

And the results are:

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ MapId ║ MapName ║ IndexId ║ IndexName ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ M1      ║       1 ║ A         ║
║     2 ║ M2      ║       2 ║ B         ║
║    -1 ║ Unknown ║       3 ║ C         ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: One more thing. When I put it in a stored procedure and pass parameter as -1 to get all unknowns it returns empty.

Comment: @buffer_overflow Well, I have no idea what your stored procedure is doing and which table is searching

Comment: Figured I need to put that select statement AS table and query on that table. Thanks.